# Reinitialize PHP array for new JSON data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making an AJAX request and attempting to parse the returned data. It seems that my `$echoArray` is not emptying on each call but is incrementing. I need a new array back each time. I also am having trouble accessing the values in the returned data.

How do I reinitialize the array in the script so that only the new data is returned and the index does not increment? How then do I access this data?

**The AJAX call:**

```
$j.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/ajax_calls/updatePrices.php",
    data: { 'vendorID': IDs, 'product_id': product_id}
    }).done(function(data) {
        //var data= JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('The data is ' + data);
            console.log('Range start is data[1].tier2_range_start: ' + data[1].tier2_range_start);
            //console.log('Range start is data.tier2_range_start: ' + data.tier2_range_start);
            console.log('Range start is data[0].tier2_range_start: ' + data[0].tier2_range_start);
            console.log('Range start is data.tier2_range_start[1]: ' + data.tier2_range_start[1]);
            console.log('Range start is data.tier2_range_start[0]: ' + data.tier2_range_start[0]); 
        for(i=0; i<IDs.length; i++)
        {   
            var vendor = IDs[i]; 
            var basePrice = simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected];

            if (qty < data.tier2_range_start){
                simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= basePrice * qty;
            }
            else if (qty > data.tier2_range_start){
                simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= (basePrice * qty) * data.tier2_discount;
            }
            else if (qty > data.tier3_range_start){
                simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= (basePrice * qty) * data.tier3_discount;
            }
            else if (qty > data.tier4_range_start){
                simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= (basePrice * qty) * data.tier4_discount;
            }
            else if (qty > data.tier5_range_start){
                simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= (basePrice * qty) * data.tier5_discount;
            }
            else{
                console.log('Something went wrong');
            }

        }
        $j('.details'+vendor+ ' .priceBlock').empty();
        $j('.details'+vendor+ ' .priceBlock').append('<span>'+simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]+'</span>');
    });
```

**Script called:**

```
<?php
require_once('/var/www/Staging/connect.php');

//post variable
$IDArray= $_POST['vendorID'];
$product_id= $_POST['product_id'];
$echoArray= array();

for($x=0; $x< sizeof($IDArray); $x++) //Query for each vendor ID in array
{
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tier_pricing WHERE vendor_id=' . $IDArray[$x]. ' AND product_id=' . $product_id;
    foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
        $echoArray[$x]['vendor_id']= $row['vendor_id'];
            $echoArray[$x]['tier2_range_start']= $row['tier2_range_start'];
        $echoArray[$x]['tier2_range_stop']= $row['tier2_range_stop'];
        $echoArray[$x]['tier3_range_start']= $row['tier3_range_start'];
        $echoArray[$x]['tier3_range_stop']= $row['tier3_range_stop'];
        $echoArray[$x]['tier4_range_start']= $row['tier4_range_start'];
        $echoArray[$x]['tier4_range_stop']= $row['tier4_range_stop'];
        $echoArray[$x]['tier5_range_start']= $row['tier5_range_start'];
        $echoArray[$x]['tier2_discount']= $row['tier2_discount'];
        $echoArray[$x]['tier3_discount']= $row['tier3_discount'];
        $echoArray[$x]['tier4_discount']= $row['tier4_discount'];
        $echoArray[$x]['tier5_discount']= $row['tier5_discount'];
    }
}
echo json_encode($echoArray); 
?>
```

**Console.log(data):**

See the incrementing. This is after two AJAX calls to the script. When it gets to a third call it returns an empty set of data []:

```
[11:54:52.090] The data is {"1":{"vendor_id":"3","tier2_range_start":"5","tier2_range_stop":"20","tier3_range_start":"20","tier3_range_stop":"100","tier4_range_start":"100","tier4_range_stop":"500","tier5_range_start":"500","tier2_discount":"2","tier3_discount":"3.1","tier4_discount":"4.3","tier5_discount":"5"}}
[11:55:14.002] The data is {"2":{"vendor_id":"3","tier2_range_start":"5","tier2_range_stop":"20","tier3_range_start":"20","tier3_range_stop":"100","tier4_range_start":"100","tier4_range_stop":"500","tier5_range_start":"500","tier2_discount":"2","tier3_discount":"3.1","tier4_discount":"4.3","tier5_discount":"5"}}
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ - your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Also, have you checked either the raw output of the AJAX call or your server logs to see if an error is getting thrown?

Comment: What do I need to put in there to prevent the SQL injection? Hold on a sec for errors

Comment: Follow the link I posted in my previous comment - there are several different methods you could use.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that, sorry. Thanks. Reviewing errors now.

Comment: My suspicion is that the variable `IDs` is not quite right.  Can you `console.log` that before making your AJAX call?

Comment: `{"1":{"vendor_id":"3" ....` is not an array anyway, its an "Object" with a property "1" and that will also not work on client side.

Comment: Yeah no PHP errors. Response Body: {"2":{"vendor_id":"3","tier2_range_start":"5","tier2_range_stop":"20","tier3_range_start":"20","tier3_range_stop":"100","tier4_range_start":"100","tier4_range_stop":"500","tier5_range_start":"500","tier2_discount":"2","tier3_discount":"3.1","tier4_discount":"4.3","tier5_discount":"5"}}

Comment: Console.log(IDs) seems to be correct. = [13:00:45.509] ["5", "3"]

Comment: @AxelAmthor what change do you suggest?

Comment: please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one of the queries is not having a result, you got a "hole" in the array:

q0, q1, q3, q4

lets assume, q0 is not having a result set, your array looks like

```
array (
1: result ...,
2: result ...,
3: result ...,
4: result ...,
)
```

index 0 is undefined. According to [this](http://www.naden.de/blog/vorsicht-php-json_encode-und-numerische-arrays), the resulting json will be an object rather than an array.

You should in any case initialise array values:
(its bad behaviour to let PHP do the auto init)

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tier_pricing WHERE vendor_....

    if ( !isset($echoArray[$x]) )
       $echoArray[$x] = array();

    foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
        $echoArray[$x]['vendor_id']= $row['vendor_id'];
```

Comment: COOL! How then do I access the data? I'm trying the following within the for loop within the ajax done function:  if(data.tier2_range_start[vendor])
       console.log('Range start is data.tier2_range_start: ' + data.tier2_range_start[vendor]);

Comment: Also tried with data[vendor].tier2_range_start and data.vendor.tier2_range_start

Comment: Example data logs as: [13:43:01.922] The data is [[],{"vendor_id":"3","tier2_range_start":"5","tier2_range_stop":"20","tier3_range_start":"20","tier3_range_stop":"100","tier4_range_start":"100","tier4_range_stop":"500","tier5_range_start":"500","tier2_discount":"2","tier3_discount":"3.1","tier4_discount":"4.3","tier5_discount":"5"}]

Comment: Started new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798968/issue-accessing-json-object-values