# Issue accessing json object values

Tags: jquery, json

I am having an issue console.logging the values from the json object sent back from my jquery ajax call to a script.

The script:

```
for(i=0; i<IDs.length; i++)
    {
        var vendor = IDs[i]; 
        $j.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax_calls/updatePrices.php",
                data: { 'vendorID': vendor, 'product_id': product_id}
                }).done(function(data) {
                    console.log('The data is ' + data);

                        var basePrice = simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected];

                        //if(data.tier2_range_start[i])
                            console.log('Range start is data.tier2_range_start: ' + data.tier2_range_start);

                        if (qty < data.tier2_range_start){
                            simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= basePrice * qty;
                        }
                        else if (qty > data.tier2_range_start){
                            simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= (basePrice * qty) * data.tier2_discount;
                        }
                        else if (qty > data.tier3_range_start){
                            simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= (basePrice * qty) * data.tier3_discount;
                        }
                        else if (qty > data.tier4_range_start){
                            simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= (basePrice * qty) * data.tier4_discount;
                        }
                        else if (qty > data.tier5_range_start){
                            simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]= (basePrice * qty) * data.tier5_discount;
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log('Something went wrong');
                        }


                    $j('.details'+vendor+ ' .priceBlock').empty();
                    $j('.details'+vendor+ ' .priceBlock').append('<span>'+simpleArray[vendor][colorSelected]+'</span>');
                });
        }//end for
```

Script called:

```
    <?php
require_once('/var/www/Staging/connect.php');

//post variable
$ID= $_POST['vendorID'];
$product_id= $_POST['product_id'];
$echoArray= array();

    //if ( !isset($echoArray[$x]) )
            //$echoArray[$x] = array();
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tier_pricing WHERE vendor_id=' . $ID. ' AND product_id=' . $product_id;
    foreach ($con->query($sql) as $row) {
        $echoArray['vendor_id']= $row['vendor_id'];
            $echoArray['tier2_range_start']= $row['tier2_range_start'];
        $echoArray['tier2_range_stop']= $row['tier2_range_stop'];
        $echoArray['tier3_range_start']= $row['tier3_range_start'];
        $echoArray['tier3_range_stop']= $row['tier3_range_stop'];
        $echoArray['tier4_range_start']= $row['tier4_range_start'];
        $echoArray['tier4_range_stop']= $row['tier4_range_stop'];
        $echoArray['tier5_range_start']= $row['tier5_range_start'];
        $echoArray['tier2_discount']= $row['tier2_discount'];
        $echoArray['tier3_discount']= $row['tier3_discount'];
        $echoArray['tier4_discount']= $row['tier4_discount'];
        $echoArray['tier5_discount']= $row['tier5_discount'];
    }

echo json_encode($echoArray); 
?>
```

Data is logging as (for example, on a loop without empty data object):

```
[15:06:13.397] The data is {"vendor_id":"3","tier2_range_start":"5","tier2_range_stop":"20","tier3_range_start":"20","tier3_range_stop":"100","tier4_range_start":"100","tier4_range_stop":"500","tier5_range_start":"500","tier2_discount":"2","tier3_discount":"3.1","tier4_discount":"4.3","tier5_discount":"5"}
```

**Why is data.tier2_range_start undefined?**

Comment: In the request, what is `IDs`?

Comment: Your data is already an array, so you don't need to JSON.parse it. Though, i don't quite understand the json you're returning. It's an array with mixed values, the first two values are empty arrays, and the third is an object representing a vendor.

Comment: I just posted the script that I am calling above. I need the values for each vendor ID that I call from the database (more than one SQL request) so I attempted to echo back a matrix array and access it as a json object. I'm not sure what to change, or how to access at this point. Was trying to avoid making a seperate ajax call for each vendor ID

Comment: @ExplosionPills ID's could be [5,4] for example

Comment: Okay, I completely changed everything to make a seperate ajax call for each ID and I am still having trouble accessing values. See changes above!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem lies in `data[vendor].tier2_range_start`.

If all the responses you get from the server have the same form as your example (`[Array, Array, Object]`) your code will only work if `vendor=2`. Otherwise you will be trying to access a member in an array that does not exists or accessing an nonexistent element.

So you may check if using he values from `IDs` as indexes is really what you want.

Comment: I changed all my code around so that I am only returning one data set at a time. See above. Why can't I access a value with data.tier2_range_start when data is returned?

Answer (score 0):

I had to put var data= JSON.parse(data); in my jquery. Anyone know why?

Comment: Unless you specify the type you are expecting with `dataType` jQuery will try to guess it. Maybe he just failed to recognize that was JSON?

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell jQuery that the returning data is json, how should jQuery know unless you put an appropriate mime header in your response?

somewhere in the beginning of your PHP: `header('Content-type: text/json');`

in your ajax:

```
...
data: { 'vendorID': vendor, 'product_id': product_id},
dataType: "json",
...
```

then jQuery is doing the job for you. And your trace should look like

```
[15:06:13.397] The data is Object object
```

Comment: The json_encode function in the Php doesn't do the trick? lol.

Comment: @CaitliNHavener: how will you pass a json string, retrieved from the server, back to the server to json_encode that? Its on the client side where the json string needs to be converted to a JS object. This is done by jQuery Ajax, usually, when jQuery knows that data is json.

Comment: [PHP Object] => json_encode() ==== **send** ====> Browser/JS (jQuery, eval, JSON.parse(), ...) ==> JavaScript Object ==> "object.property"